# Get Div Location with Responsive Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div on a page that acts as an overlay for the entire page when a button is pressed. Here is the problem I'm having:

When the overlay is showing, I am using Javascript to position the overlay starting at the top of a div on a page using the following method:

```
var elementTop = $("#myVideo").offset().top;
$('#lightBoxBackground').css('top', elementTop);
```

However, when I change the size of the page, rather than dynamically getting the new position of the `myVideo` div, it seems like it keeps the original position. So, as I expand my page, the overlay div stays where it was opened rather than constantly moving with the `myVideo` div.

Is there a way to dynamically continue getting the new position of a div as the page layout changes using html, css, and javascript so that way my overlay div moves with the `myVideo` div? I'm new to JavaScript and have checked through a lot of questions, but haven't found anything useful.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using javascript you could listen for width/height changes on the window with `.resize()`

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    //resize just happened, update your positioning values
});
```

Note: This solution uses jQuery - https://api.jquery.com/resize/